# How to create 'x' quantity of input type text based on a previous input type range value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to creat a certain amount of inputs based on a input range value that the user chooses previously.

Here is the input range:

```
<div class="line1">

<h4>Quantity</h4>

<input type="range" min="3" max="20" class="form-control" name="qtd" oninput="display.value=value" onchange="display.value=value">

<input type="text" id="display" readonly class="form-control">

</div>
```

And with this value, I'd like to create more of this pair (both of them, each pair below each other) of inputs:

```
<div class="line1-1">

<h4>Tag</h4>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="etiqueta" placeholder="Etiqueta" autocomplete="off" required>

</div>

<div class="line1-1">

<h4>Num</h4>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de Série" autocomplete="off" id="modelo" name="modelo" required>

</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include code

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to make requests for code. You've told us what you want, but haven't shown what you've tried. We expect that you will do you research and make an attempt before posting here. And, when you do post, we expect that it will be a specific question about what you've tried. There are many ways to do what you are asking and, as such, your question is likely to be closed as being "too broad".

Comment: You have to show us what you have tried so far, if you are looking for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd group the two divs you want to be replicated inside a single div and set the display property of it to **none**.

```
<div id="master" style="display:none;">
  <div class="line1-1">
    <h4>Tag</h4>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="etiqueta" placeholder="Etiqueta" autocomplete="off" required>
  </div>
  <div class="line1-1">
    <h4>Num</h4>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de Série" autocomplete="off" id="modelo" name="modelo" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way the div acts as an invisible template you can simply clone using the **cloneNode()** method and append the clones to an empty div container.

Here's an example:

```js
function process(e) {
  document.getElementById("display").value = e.target.value;
  document.getElementById("duplicates").innerHTML = "";

  var clone;
  for (var a = 0; a < parseInt(e.target.value); a++) {
    clone = document.getElementById("master").cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute("style", "");
    document.getElementById("duplicates").appendChild(clone);
  }
}
document.getElementById("qtd").addEventListener("input", process);
document.getElementById("qtd").addEventListener("change", process);
```

```html
<div class="line1">
  <h4>Quantity</h4>
  <input type="range" min="3" max="20" class="form-control" name="qtd" id="qtd">
  <input type="text" id="display" readonly class="form-control">
</div>
<div id="master" style="display:none;">
  <div class="line1-1">
    <h4>Tag</h4>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="etiqueta" placeholder="Etiqueta" autocomplete="off" required>
  </div>
  <div class="line1-1">
    <h4>Num</h4>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de Série" autocomplete="off" id="modelo" name="modelo" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="duplicates">
```

Comment: Sometimes I just can't resist Scott - it's the little helper inside me. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know how things work here. I didn't mean to ask for a code, if someone could point me some instructions and materials, where to study or to look for, it would be great already.

Comment: You're question might be a bit too specific to simply point you to somewhere. Nevertheless my answer above - and more importantly the sample - provide you first aid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your HTML code.

```html
<div class="line1">

  <h4>Quantity</h4>

  <input type="range" min="3" max="20" class="form-control" name="qtd" oninput="document.getElementById('display').value=this.value" onchange="document.getElementById('display').value=this.value">

  <input type="text" id="display" readonly class="form-control">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. I added a div to put the resulting controls in. What I did was take your desired html result, put it into a template and then loop through as many times as the range element returns every time it changed.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="line1">
   <h4>Quantity</h4>
   <input type="range" id="range" min="3" max="20" name="qtd" />
   <input type="text" id="display" readonly />
   <div id="more"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
   const range = document.querySelector("#range")
   const display = document.querySelector("#display")
   const more = document.querySelector("#more")

   range.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const val = e.target.value
    display.value = val
    createFormElements(Number(val))
   })

   function createFormElements(num) {
    let html = ''

    for (let i = 1; i <= num; i+=1) {
     html += `
<div class="line1-1">
 <h4>Tag</h4>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="etiqueta" placeholder="Etiqueta" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<div class="line1-1">
 <h4>Num ${i}</h4>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de Série" autocomplete="off" id="modelo-${i}" name="modelo" required>
</div>`
    }

    more.innerHTML = html
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```